# Outlook 2007 Property Change not firing when removing recipients

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing an outlook add-in for 2007+ which listens to the property change event and displays a list of recipients to the user.

My issue is in 2007 the property change event does not fire when a recipient is removed from the message causing a conflict between what the add-in displays and and what the user has in the TO/CC and BCC fields.

Note: You can force the property change event to fire by saving the message however this is not a elegant solution moving forward.

Question: Is there a solution to this bug in Outlook?

Comment: I cannot see that behavior in OutlookSpy - create new message, click CurrentItem on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the Events tab. Every time a recipient is added or removed, PropertyChange(To)/PropertyChange(CC)/PropertyChange(BCC) events fire.

Comment: Hi Dmitry,

I'm running Outlook 2007 SP3 in our development environment I have disabled all the add-ins except outlook spy and I can re create the issue.

Can you give this a try:

1) Add an address in the TO field (verify property change event then clear log)
2) Remove the address from the TO field (No property change event fired)

Comment: Also if you save the message after removing a recipient the property change event fires!

Comment: Hmmm.. I don't have Outlook 2007 handy (only 2010 and 2013). Do you only see this in Outlook 2007?

Comment: Yes this is only an issue within Outlook 2007. 2010 & 2013 fire the property change event when removing recipients.

Can you suggest another method I could use to access the recipients of the mail message? The main issue with the property change event not firing when a recipient is removed is that outlook seems to use this event as a mechanism to update the underlying recipients object meaning I can't simply poll the mail item for changes periodically because the list still contains the deleted recipient.

Comment: I don't know if there is a workaround, sorry...

Comment: I had a forms timer going every 300ms saving the messages. This worked in most cases, however on slower machines it crashed Outlook and you lose the prompt for "do you want to save this draft" so the user would end up with tons of empty drafts if they were in the habit of cancelling their message. We decided to let the user know that Outlook 2007 has a known bug which prevents us from updating our custom task pane because of the recipient refresh bug and that Microsoft fixed it in 2010 and 2013.

Comment: Hi Muffin Man. I tried something similar but had the same problem. Outlook seems to crash on slower when saving the message in quick succession. Seems the only solution is to update your product to not use PropertyChange for Outlook 2007 as it is not reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long time working on this issue I was unable to find a work around.

The PropertyChange event is used as a mechanism within Outlook to update the internal recipients collection and because this does not fire when a recipient is removed there was no way to preserve a consistent user experience and retrieve the updated list of recipients using the Outlook object model.

This is purely a bug in Outlook 2007 and does not affect versions 2010 and 2013.

Additional notes: Saving the message will cause the PropertyChangeEvent to fire and update the recipients.

Comment: I've also confirmed this in Outlook Spy. Removing a recipient will not update the object model and therefore MAPI isn't notified so you can't go lower level to bypass Outlook. This was probably never an issue for Microsoft as the recipient was removed from the UI and therefore difficult to realize it was happening.